# Insert record if given numbers does not exists between the existing ranges

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Suppose I have a database structure like this.

```
sp_frommem    sp_tomem
    1           1000
```

Now if I want to insert a new record where `sp_frommem` is 5 (example) and `sp_tomem` is 750 (example) then it would return error like "You cannot insert database within this range as a range covering this range already exists". But, if I try to insert a new record where `sp_frommem` is any number greater than 1000 (say for example 1500) and `sp_tomem` is any number greater than `sp_formem`, then the record insertion should be successful.

Now suppose I have more fields in the table.

```
sp_frommem    sp_tomem
    1           1000
    1500        4000
    4001        7500
```

Now here I can insert a record containing any number from 1001 to 1499 (as this range is still free) and any number from 7501 to above in the record. How to achieve this? I tried to put a check with the following query but its not working as expected.

```
$chk = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM signup_promotion WHERE sp_frommem >= :from or sp_tomem <= :to");
$chk-> bindValue(':from', $from);
$chk-> bindValue(':to', $to);
$chk-> execute();
$chf = $chk->fetch();

  if($chf['cnt'] > 0){
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>A Signup Bonus within the ranges mentioned already exists.</div>";
  }else{
    // INSERT RECORD HERE
  }
```

Comment: You can use the `BETWEEN` keyword to make things a little easier to read: `WHERE :number BETWEEN sp_frommem AND sp_tomem`

Comment: @aynber there are two different numbers though.. `$from` and `$to` what to do?

Comment: Then I'd probably suggest `WHERE :from BETWEEN sp_frommem AND sp_tomem OR :to BETWEEN sp_frommem AND sp_tomem` to check both the from and to numbers.

Comment: perfect.. make it an answer and I will +1 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM signup_promotion WHERE (:from BETWEEN sp_frommem AND sp_tomem) OR (:to BETWEEN sp_frommem AND sp_tomem)
```

should work. Just compare if `cnt` equals zero (this are the collisions). You could also use:

```
SELECT * FROM signup_promotion WHERE (:from BETWEEN sp_frommem AND sp_tomem) OR (:to BETWEEN sp_frommem AND sp_tomem)
```

and output the collisions to give the user an overview when timeslots are available.

Comment: This will not find an overlap between (1:100) and (10:90).

Answer (score 0):

You need this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM signup_promotion
WHERE sp_frommem <= :to
  AND sp_tomem   >= :from
```

Note that `(:from BETWEEN sp_frommem AND sp_tomem) OR (:to BETWEEN sp_frommem AND sp_tomem)` will not cover the case when `(:from, :to) = (1, 100)` and `(sp_frommem, sp_tomem) = (10, 90)`, because neither `1` nor `100` is between `10` and `90`.

You can also improve the performance with an EXISTS subquery:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM signup_promotion
    WHERE sp_frommem <= :to
      AND sp_tomem   >= :from
) as xst
```

This way the query will stop searching as soon as an overlap has been found.